# Display a different URL for a subdomain

Tags: html, .htaccess, dns

I've developed an application that a client might access at a URL like this: http://example.com. In this case, I own and control http://example.com.

I now have a case where another company would like present my application as their own by changing some of the branding and the URL (say: http://companyx.com). The application and all the data will still remain hosed with me just like it was at http://example.com.

What's the best way to handle this? I was going to create a separate directory for this company so I can update the branding (mainly just a logo) to make it specific to them, but I'm not sure how I can make this directory accessible to people going to a directory on the company site (http://companyx.com). Using sub-domains is also an option if this makes it easier. Assume that I'll be able to add records to companyx.com's DNS, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a separate directory, then create a subdomain at sub.example.com and point it to directory (you can do this from your hosting control panel). Now your company needs to point their desired url (within their domain) to your subdomain.

IMHO this is the cleanest solution, if you need to have control over the site's content.

---

edit

what company needs to do is to point cname record of domain to your url and it should work, (otherwise you will need to get separate ip for your subdomain in order to point A record there)

Comment: what would the company need to do with their dns records (or whatever) in order to point it to my subdomain?

Comment: This makes sense overall. I'm not totally clear on "create a subdomain at sub.example.com and point it to directory" I have the separate directory (example.com/companyx) and created a new subdomain (companyx.example.com), but not sure how to point the subdomain to the directory. In my "settings" for the subdomain, my only option is to redirect it to another URL. Is this what you mean?

Comment: No it isn't. I'll explain but what is your hosting control panel ?

Comment: It is cpanel (host is bluehost)

Comment: look for "Document Root" on subdomains page and enter there path to your directory in which is your subdomain, this is all

Comment: Got that. What about on the company side? How do they direct a subdomain to serve up the pages from my subdirectory without changing the URL? Is this a DNS CNAME issue or something else?

Comment: @jonmrich CNAME record pointing to your subdomain should do the trick (value of cname record will be url of your subdomain)

Comment: Cool...thanks. And this will keep the domain as, say, client.companyx.com and not change to example.com/clientx?

Comment: @jonmrich yes it should, there are some other workarounds involving html redirects in case this solution won't work for you, please accept my answer if it's working